# error_reporting(0) hides regular output? Strange behavior

Tags: php, apache, error-reporting

A customer is running a Magento webshop, but there is a very strange behavior with the `error_reporting` function in combination with magento.

As I know the function, it hides of shows error/warning/notice-messages and does not influence  the regular output of the script (e.g. with "echo").

I've got a short example script with two `echo`-calls. In dependency, if error_reporting() is on or off, one or two lines of output are visible at the browser. I've expected, that this function does not effect the regular output?

[image]

- There are two `echo`-calls in the script: At line 9 and 31.
- With error_handling(0), only the first `echo`-call sends output, the output of the second echo will be ignored.

In my opinion it's not the acutally excepted behavior of the `error_reporting()` function. I tried to change CHMOD (644,666,755,777), but no change. `display_errors` also doesn't change the output.

Here are two screenshots (look at the GET-Parameter at the address line of the browser and in line 6 or 7 of the script:

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Please include the code as code not as an image.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: What happens when you switch `E_ALL` with `0`, and `0` with `E_ALL`... is it reversed?

Comment: @Arian: It depends, if a GET-parameter is used. With GET-Parameter it takes `E_ALL`, without GET-parameter it takes the `0`. That's the reason there are two screenshots from google chrome. Or didn't get your question right? But yes, it is reversed. Just tried :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

See if that throws any errors you were missing.

**Update 1:**

- grep or find in folder all error_reporting and display_errors in your codebase and remove them. Have your code the only place that does the error settings. It could be something Magneto is doing that is changing this.

Comment: error_reporting(-1) behaves same like error_reporting(E_ALL), which means: Both lines of output ...